# What is the explicit form of $\tau^{\alpha\beta}$ in the linearized Einstein field equations $\Box h^{\alpha\beta}=-16\pi\tau^{\alpha\beta}$?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, linearized-theory

If we let $h^{\alpha\beta}=\eta^{\alpha\beta}-g^{\alpha\beta}\sqrt{|det(g)|}$ then, according to wikipedia, the Einstein Field Equations become $$\Box h^{\alpha\beta}=-16\pi\tau^{\alpha\beta},$$ where $\Box$ is the d'Alembertian and $\tau^{\alpha\beta}$ is "the stress–energy tensor plus quadratic terms involving $h^{\alpha\beta}$." All I'm really asking for is what $\tau^{\alpha\beta}$ is explicitly, and possibly a link to a source for the derivation of the above equations and how they are derived from the Einstein Field Equations.

Comment: Can you please link the specific article in Wikipedia?

Comment: Sorry, haven't checked my account in ages; but here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave under "Mathematics."